# Efficient SQL schema and query design for top recent user audit table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, scaling

I'd like some input on designing the SQL data layer for a service that should store and provide the latest N entries for a specific user. The idea is to track each user (id), the time of an event and then the event id.

The service should only respond with the last X numbers of events for each user, and also only contain the events that occured during the last Y number of days.
The service also needs to scale to large amounts of updates and reads.

I'm considering just a simple table with the fields:

```
ID | USERID | EVENT            | TIMESTAMP
============================================
1  | 1      | created file Z   | 2014-03-20
2  | 2      | deleted dir Y    | 2014-03-20
3  | 1      | created dir Y    | 2014-03-20
```

But how would you consider solving the temporal requirements? I see two alternatives here:

1) On insert and/or reads for a user, also remove outdated and all but the last X events for a user. Affects latency as you need to perform both select,delete and insert on each request. But it keeps the disk size to minimum.

2) Let the service filter on query and do pruning as a separate batch job with some sql that:

- First removes all obsolete events irrespective of users based on the timestamp.
- Then do some join that removes all but the last X events for each user.

I have looked for design principles regarding these requirements which seems like fairly common ones. But I haven't yet found a perfect match.

It is at the moment NOT a requirement to query for all users that have performed a specific type of events.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The service is meant to scale to millions of requests / hour so I've been playing around with the idea of denormalizing this for performance reasons. Given that the requirements are set in stone:

- 10 last events
- No events older than 10 days

I'm actually considering a pivoted table like this:

```
USERID | EV_1   | TS_1   | EV_2  | TS_2   | EV_3  | TS_3   | etc up to 10...
======================================================================
1      | Create | 2014.. | Del x | 2013.. | etc.. | 2013.. |
```

This way I can probably shift the events with a MERGE with SELECT and I get eviction for "free". Then I only have to purge all records where TS_1 is older than 10 days. I can also filter in my application logic to only show the events that are newer than 10 days after doing the trivial selects.

The caveat is if events comes in "out of order". The idea above works if I can always guarantee that the events are ordered from "left to right". Probably have to think a bit on that one..

Aside from the fact that it is basically a big cut in the relational data model, do you think I'm on the right track here if it comes to prioritize performance above all?

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is good. Consider also the indexes you want to use. In practice, you will need a multi-column index on (userid, timestamp) to quickly respond to queries that query the last N events having a certain userid. Then you need a single-column index on (timestamp) to efficiently delete old events.

How many events you're planning to store and how many events you're planning to retrieve per query? I.e. does the size of the table exceed the RAM available? Are you using traditional spinning hard disks or solid-state disks? If the size of the table exceeds the RAM available and you are using traditional HDDs, note that each row returned for the query takes about 5-15 milliseconds due to slow seek time.

If your system supports batch jobs, I would use a batch job to delete old events instead of deleting old events at each query. The reason is that batch jobs do not slow down the interactive code path, and can perform more work at once provided that you execute the batch job rarely enough.

If your system doesn't support batch jobs, you could use a probabilistic algorithm to delete old events, i.e. delete only with 1% probability if events are queried. Or alternatively, you could have a helper table into which you store the timestamp of the last deleting of old events, and then check that timestamp and if it's old enough then perform new delete job and update the timestamp. The helper table should be so small that it will always stay in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination is not to delete data.  I would just store the data in your structure and have an interface (perhaps a view or table functions) that runs a query such as;

```
select s.*
from simple s
where s.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - interval 'n days' and
      s.UserId = $userid
order by s.timestamp desc
fetch first 10 row only;
```

(Note:  this uses standard syntax because you haven't specified the database, but there is similar functionality in any database.)

For performance, you want an index on `simple(UserId, timestamp)`.  This will do most of the work.

If you really want, you can periodically delete older rows.  However, keeping all the rows is advantageous for responding to changing requirements ("Oh, we now want 60 days instead of 30 days") or other purposes, such as investigations into user behaviors and changes in events over time.

There are situations that are out-of-the-ordinary where you might want a different approach.  For instance, there could be legal restrictions on the amount of time you could hold the data.  In that case, use a job that deletes old data and run it every day.  Or, if your database technology were an in-memory database, you might want to restrict the size of the table so old data doesn't occupy much memory.  Or, if you had really high transaction volumes and lost of users (like millions of users with thousands of events), you might be more concerned with data volume affecting performance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The service will have very high transaction numbers, so in my case I really need to keep the database size to a minimum. But there seems to be consensus on supportive batch jobs which has also been my idea. I guess the million dollar question then becomes how to structure the pruning statement and when to start it.

Comment: @Billybong . . . In a high transaction environment where you really want to minimize the size of the database, then you should be looking into partitioning.  Dropping a partitioning is much, much, much faster than deleting lots and lots of rows.